# CodeDeploy doesn't run automatically after updating a service in ECS (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, settings, updates, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

On "Step 1:Configure service" of ECS Service setting,

[image]

I changed the Revison to "`54 (latest)`" from "`53`" for update.

[image]

Then, clicked on `Skip to review`,

[image]

Clicked on `Next step`,

[image]

Finally, clicked on `Update Service`.

[image]

However, CodeDeploy doesn't run automatically after updating the service. Why doesn't CodeDeploy run automatically after updating the service?

Answer (score 0):

You clicked on `Skip to review` to skip "`Step 1:Configure service`" and other steps as well.

[image]

So your change of the Revison to "`54 (latest)`" is not applied. So the Revision is still "`53`" which means the Revision is not changed to "`54 (latest)`". The Revision keeps "53".

[image]

Remember ***"`CodeDeploy` runs automatically after updating a service if you change `task definition` or `platform version`"***. So after changing the Revison to "`54 (latest)`",

[image]

Keep clicking on `Next step`.

[image]

Then, click on `Update Service`. Finally, CodeDeploy will run automatically after updating the service.

[image]